# Python, write json / dictionary objects to a file iteratively (one at a time)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a large `for loop` in which I create json objects and I would like to be able to stream write the object in each iteration to a file. I would like to be able to use the file later in a similar fashion later (read objects one at a time).
My json objects contain newlines and I can't just dump each object as a line in a file.
How can I achieve this?

To make it more concrete, consider the following:

```
for _id in collection:
    dict_obj = build_dict(_id)  # build a dictionary object 
    with open('file.json', 'a') as f:
        stream_dump(dict_obj, f)
```

`stream_dump` is the function that I want.

Note that I don't want to create a large list and dump the whole list using something like `json.dump(obj, file)`. I want to be able to append the object to the file in each iteration.

Thanks.

Comment: If I dont understand your question wrong it seems possible to write a seperator line that your data doesnt have like "-----" in every iteration after you write object and when reading create a new object when you see that seperator.

Comment: Ah, I see. That definitely works. I thought there might be other stream processing solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to work with a subclass of `JSONEncoder` and then proxy the `build_dict` function

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,)
#                        unicode_literals)

import collections
import json


mycollection = [1, 2, 3, 4]


def build_dict(_id):
    d = dict()
    d['my_' + str(_id)] = _id
    return d


class SeqProxy(collections.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, func, coll, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SeqProxy, *args, **kwargs)

        self.func = func
        self.coll = coll

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.coll)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.func(self.coll[key])


class JsonEncoderProxy(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        try:
            iterable = iter(o)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            return list(iterable)
        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)


jsonencoder = JsonEncoderProxy()
collproxy = SeqProxy(build_dict, mycollection)


for chunk in jsonencoder.iterencode(collproxy):
    print(chunk)
```

Ouput:

```
[
{
"my_1"
:
1
}
,
{
"my_2"
:
2
}
,
{
"my_3"
:
3
}
,
{
"my_4"
:
4
}
]
```

To read it back chunk by chunk you need to use `JSONDecoder` and pass a callable as `object_hook`. This hook will be called with each new decoded object (each `dict` in your list) when you call `JSONDecoder.decode(json_string)`

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. Just a question, what does `SeqProxy` do?

Comment: Your collection will not return a "dict" for each item (you are calling `build_dict` on each item) and `SeqProxy` wraps your collection and returns the result of `build_dict` when the `JSONEncoder` requests the next item in the list to serialize it.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: This solves two problems: (a) the proxies are needed to call the custom `build_dict` function on a specific subset of the collection; (b) the task of serialising chunk by chunk is already provided by the JSON module through the `iterencode` function. – I focused on (b) and didn't understand the code until realising it was all about (a).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are generating the files yourself, you can simply write out one JSON object per line:

```
for _id in collection:
    dict_obj = build_dict(_id)  # build a dictionary object 
    with open('file.json', 'a') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(dict_obj))
        f.write('\n')
```

And then read them in by iterating over lines:

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        dict_obj = json.loads(line)
```

This isn't a great general solution, but it's a simple one if you are both the generator and consumer.

Answer (score -4):

Simplest solution:

Remove all whitespace characters from your json document:

```
import string

def remove_whitespaces(txt):
    """ We shall remove all whitespaces"""
    for chr in string.whitespace:
        txt = txt.replace(chr)
```

Obviously you could also `json.dumps(json.loads(json_txt))` (BTW this also verify that the text is a valid json).

Now you could write you documents to a file one line each.

Second solution:

Create an [AnyStr]Io stream, write in the Io a valid document, (your documents being part of an object or list) and then write the io in a file (or upload it to the cloud).

Comment: And what happens if whitespace is an integral part of the content?

Comment: Good observation! Anyway json.dumps(json.loads(json_txt)) would be perfect in this case.

Comment: Why would you want to remove all whitespace? I don't see how this is connected to the OP. If you want to have the complete JSON dump on a single line, do `json.dump(... indent=None)` (actually, it's the default already). Newlines inside text nodes are escaped anyway.